# Allocate structure in another function in c

Tags: c, function, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

how can I allocate memory for structure in another function than where is structure variable declared?

```
typedef struct{
    char *IP_req;
} ARGS;

int main(int argc , char *argv[]){
    ARGS *args = NULL;
    mal(argc, argv, &args);
    printf("arg IP:%s\n", &args->IP_req);
    return 0;
}
```

Function where I want to allocate:

```
int mal(int argc , char *argv[], ARGS *args){
    args=malloc(sizeof (ARGS));
    args->IP_req = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
    strcpy(args->IP_req,"12.21.51.88");
    printf("arg IP:%s\n", args->IP_req);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this program, I get:
**arg IP:12.21.51.88

arg IP:(null)**

But I expected (and want):
**arg IP:12.21.51.88

arg IP:12.21.51.88**

Comment: What's `mal`? What's `ARGS`?

Comment: mal stands for malloc and ARGS are program arguments. I reduced program to minimum...

Comment: Turn warnings of your compiler on: `ARGS *args` must be `ARGS **args` and then `*args=malloc(sizeof (ARGS));`

Comment: sorry, i forget to include my struct (ARGS). I edited post, please look...

Comment: Explanation: with passing `&args` you pass the address of the variable, so the function must _dereference_ it to place the allocated memory in the variable.

Comment: Um... you're passing `&args`, type `ARGS**`,  to `mal` as the third argument which (incorrectly) expects `ARGS *`. Are you saying that  does *not* generate a compiler warning? If not, seriously... turn up your warning levels and treat them as errors. That should have flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Finding the Error

This statement in `main`:

```
mal(argc, argv, &args);
```

says to pass the address of `args` to `mal`. The type of `args` is `ARGS *`, so the type of `&args` is `ARGS **`.

This definition of `mal`:

```
int mal(int argc , char *argv[], ARGS *args)
```

says that the `args` parameter has type `ARGS *`. Since `main` is passing an `ARGS **`, not an `ARGS *`, this is an error.

If you are using your compiler correctly, it should have warned you about one of the following things:

- In `main`, no declaration of `mal` is visible.
- In `main`, the call to `mal` does not match its declaration.
- The definition of `mal` does not match its declaration.

If the compiler did not warn you about at least one of those, then you need to ensure two things are done:

- Turn on or increase warnings in your compiler. If you are using GCC or Clang via the command line, add `-Wall` to the command line switches. If you are using another interface or another compiler, refer to its documentation.
- Put a declaration of `mal` in a header file and use `#include` to include that header file in both the source file containing `main` and the source file containing `mal`.

Putting the declaration in a header file and including that file in each source file is a better solution than copying the declaration to each source file because it ensure each source file uses the same declaration. And enabling compiler warnings—and paying attention to them—ensure there is a complete chain checking the types—the use of `mal` in `main` is connected to its declaration, and its declaration is connected to its definition. This enables to compiler to do all the type checking.

### Fixing the Error

One way to fix the error is to make the definition of `mal` match how you call it in `main`. To do this, change the definition of `mal` to make `args` have type `ARGS **`:

```
int mal(int argc , char *argv[], ARGS **args)
```

Then inside, `mal`, since the type of `args` has changed, you need to use `*args` to refer to the `ARGS *` that `main` has passed to it:

```
*args = malloc(sizeof (ARGS));
(*args)->IP_req = malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
strcpy((*args)->IP_req,"12.21.51.88");
printf("arg IP:%s\n", (*args)->IP_req);
return 0;
```

### Other Notes

In `main`, when printing a string with `%s`, do not pass the address of the array, as in `printf("arg IP:%s\n", &args->IP_req);`. Pass the address of the first element of the array, using `printf("arg IP:%s\n", args->IP_req);`. (Although `args->IP_req` initially refers to the array, it is, in this and most contexts, automatically converted to a pointer to its first element.)

In C (unlike C++), you do not need to cast the result of `malloc`, so `args->IP_req = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);` can be just `args->IP_req = malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);`.

When calculating sizes to pass to `malloc`, it is better to use `sizeof` in this way:

```
*args = malloc(size **args);
args->IP_req = malloc(200 * sizeof *args->IP_req);
```

This way, the size of the object being allocated is automatically used—if later edits to the code change the type where `args` or `args->IP_req` is declared, these expressions automatically use the new size. It would be necessary to change the type in two or more places (one at the declaration and one in each `malloc`).

Comment: You're right, compiler gives me this:
malloc.c: In function ‘main’:
malloc.c:11:18: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘mal’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  mal(argc, argv, &args);
                  ^
malloc.c:7:5: note: expected ‘ARGS * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’ but argument is of type ‘ARGS ** {aka struct <anonymous> **}’
 int mal(int argc , char *argv[], ARGS *args);
     ^~~
So how to solve this??

Comment: @Eric The printf in the main also needs a modification. `printf("arg IP:%s\n", args->IP_req);`

Comment: @Eric: I have to accept that yours is the better answer! But it's been fun 'debugging' the OP's code … ***and my code***!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments by @PaulOgilvie, the last argument to `mal` should be a pointer to a pointer:

```
int mal(int argc , char *argv[], ARGS **args) { // **args poits to the pointer to be allocated
    *args = malloc(sizeof (ARGS)); // And all other 'args' herein should be dereferenced
    (*args)->IP_req = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
    strcpy((*args)->IP_req,"12.21.51.88");
    printf("arg IP:%s\n", (*args)->IP_req);
    return 0;
}
```

Your call in main: `mal(argc, argv, &args);` is correct.

Comment: `*args->IP_req` is parsed as `*(args->IP_req)`, but `args` has type `ARGS **`, so it is a pointer to a pointer, not a pointer to a structure and cannot be used with `->`. The proper code is `(*args)->IP_req`, and the other references with `args` must be changed too.

Comment: OK, so my answer isn't as thorough as Eric's, but is it really not useful? I think it shows the OP what to do to fix his/her issue!

Comment: But your code gives me some errors:
malloc.c:18:7: error: ‘*args’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
  *args->IP_req = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
       ^~
malloc.c:18:7: error: ‘*args’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
  *args->IP_req = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 200);
       ^~

Comment: @PetrMarek See comments by Eric, and check the edited code! Sorry for the mistake (typed it in too hastily).

Comment: Ok, I tried to replace *args->IP_req with (*args)->IP_req and I really can compile program without errors, but it still dont produce expected results. It gives me to stdout:
arg IP:12.21.51.88 </br>
arg IP:�bR�U (yes, strange characters!)

Comment: @PetrMarek That's another small error in your code! In main, you have `printf("arg IP:%s\n", &args->IP_req);` but this should be: `printf("arg IP:%s\n", args->IP_req);' (printf with %s want a string, not the address of a string). Try it out.